# GRUNDIG VCP 3930 Vacuum Cleaner Charging Issue - Seeking Advice on Diagnosis and Repair

Tags: repair, appliances, troubleshooting, electronics, vacuum-cleaner

I have a GRUNDIG VCP 3930 vacuum cleaner that has been reliable for several years.

Recently, it has stopped working. When I plug in the charger, the battery indicator lights up briefly and then immediately turns off. If I press the charger adapter more firmly, the charging LED flashes twice and then goes dark again. This leads me to suspect a mechanical issue, perhaps a loose connection or faulty soldering inside.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Any advice on how to diagnose and possibly fix this? I'm considering opening it up to take a look, but I would appreciate guidance on what to look for or if it's even advisable to attempt a repair.

**P.S.1.** I have also asked this [question](https://www.reddit.com/r/appliancerepair/comments/19cux0o/grundig_vcp_3930_vacuum_cleaner_charging_issue/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on r/appliancerepair subbredit.

**P.S.2.** I asked a follow-up question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/698512/124243) on electronics.stackexchange.com forum.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Several years, battery powered, I fully expect the battery is dead, based on nearly every device with a rechargable battery I've ever owned. The newer types are better/longer-lasting than the older types, but they still expire after some length of time & number of charge/discharge cycles.

With a built-in battery that often means the device is end of life unless you want to hack it, because the manufacturer usually does not support replacing the battery. But you can contact them and inquire.

Available but ridiculously expensive is also probably end of life if *ridiculously expensive* means as much or more than a whole new unit with a whole new warranty, which the replacement battery normally does not have.

Comment: Is there a way that I can check your hypothesis of the battery being dead? I see that the replacement battery is available (e.g., [here](https://fixpart.nl/nl/product/midea-17475000014890-accu?apl=2569052)), even though it is ridiculously expensive. I have a multimeter at home and know how to use/program an Arduino or a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Check the voltage on the battery without the charger plugged in, and with the charger plugged in, and after you unplug the charger. In most cases a bad battery will plummet as soon as the charger is removed from the circuit. Or if it's a lithium that has triggered it's internal protection fuse, it will have no volts.

Comment: I asked a follow-up question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/698512/124243)

Comment: Also please consider that the point of diagnostics is not just to repair but maybe sell/donate the parts to avoid it being dumped on landfields or see.